# What is file number limitation for BTRFS directory index or are there a limitation?

Tags: btrfs

I am running some experiments on a Linux machine on top of EXT4 which involves writing a larger number of files than EXT4's directory index support by default and in some cases the total number of files at the end of an experiment is unknown. Therefore simply increasing `limit` is not always an option.

For this reason, I have been looking at maybe switching to BTRFS as the base file system used for the experiments. But I have been unable to identify if the directory index BTRFS uses has a file limitation and what that number is if there is one.

Comment: What do you mean by "directory index"? Number of files in a given directory? If so, then ext4 does not have any explicit limit on the number of directory entries, altough all kinds of utilities tend to get really slow once you have tens of millions of files in a single directory, so it's always advised to split them into multiple subdirectories.

Comment: So please clarify what exactly is the limit that you're hitting.

Comment: @TooTea There is in theory no limit. But the EXT{2,3,4} directory index has a size limit: (see https://adammonsen.com/post/1555/) which limits the number of files you can put into a directory. The limitation can be increased, decreased, or removed (the latter by disabling directory index).

Comment: and I have actually hit this limit

Comment: Example of the error you will get: `kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-2): ext4_dx_add_entry: Directory index full!` - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29894